# Как дать админку в телеграмме в группе с помощью бота?

Tags: python, telebot, telegram

Возможно ли назначить админа в группу с помощью бота, который в ней администратор, используя **telebot** / **aiogram** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да! В библиотеке aiogram есть функция promoteChatMember. Используется в виде:

```
await bot.promote_chat_member(chat_id = /chat_id/, user_id = /user_id/)
```

Также есть другие параметры, подробнее сможете ознакомиться по ссылке:

- https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/dev-3.x/api/methods/promote_chat_member.html